# How to bypass ejs layout in specific pages like login page

Tags: node.js, ejs

How to render specific pages in ejs like `login` without the layout

```
app.use(express.static("public"));


// setting views engine
app.use(expressLayout);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/resources/views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple code for you

```
app.get('/Login', (req, res, next)=>{
    res.render('login');
});

app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', router);
```

Here the router handles all the routes. So before using the `expressLayouts` declare your path and you should be set.